Add normal curve to grouped histogram
for plotting histograms in R I usually use the gggpubr-package. Now I want to draw a grouped histogramm and add normal curves.
My dataset is structured as follows:
  group <- rbinom (1000, 1, 0.5)
  con <- rnorm(1000, ifelse(group == 1, 0, 4), 3)
  results_example <- data.frame(con, group)
  results_example$group <- as.factor(results_example$group)

So far I have:
gghistogram(results_example, x = "con", y = "..density..",
        add = "mean", rug = TRUE,
        fill = "group", palette = c("red", "blue")) 

Now I want to add a normal curve for eah group. Espacially, I know the theoretical distribution (as it is a simulation study), so I want to draw N(0,3) for group = 1 and N(4,3) for group = 0.
I'm actually not interessted in the density of the observed values (so I don't want to state add_density = TRUE), but I want to draw the theroetical "right" distribution as a line for each group.
Maybe someone could help me?
Thank you!

Is it required to use gghistogram?  Are you expecting the data to change a lot  or to be dynamic? I might have a solution with geom_histogram() and stat_function() that require some manual adjustment.

No, it is not required - I can use any function in R.

I am not familiar with ggpubr, but I think that you can do a lot with base ggplot.  I used geom_histogram() with transparency (alpha), added the mean with geom_vline() and one stat_function call for each group. I had to find a scaling factor , 333 seems appropriate (number of observations divided by standard deviation?).
I am not sure if this solution is efficient for a larger dataset (more groups).
library(tidyverse)

group <- rbinom (1000, 1, 0.5)
con <- rnorm(1000, ifelse(group == 1, 0, 4), 3)
results_example <- data.frame(con, group)
results_example$group <- as.factor(results_example$group)

results_example %>% ggplot(., 
       aes(x = con )) +
  geom_histogram( aes(fill = group),alpha = 0.3 , position = position_identity(), col ="black" )+
  scale_fill_manual( values =c( "red","blue"), labels = c(1,2))+
  scale_color_manual( values =c( "red","blue"), labels = c(1,2))+
  geom_vline( data=  results_example %>% group_by(group) %>%  summarise( mean = mean(con)) ,
              aes(xintercept = mean, col =group), lty = 2)+
  stat_function( fun= ~dnorm(.x, 0 ,3)*333, col ="blue")+
  stat_function( fun= ~dnorm(.x,4,3)*333, col ="red")+
  theme_classic()+ theme(legend.position = "top")
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.


Created on 2024-06-14 with reprex v2.1.0
